# What does sendSignedTransaction return?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, blockchain, mining

I want to call a method in the smart contract (UpdateWeather) that goes through several steps before returning the result (an integer). I use sendSingendTransaction but I have doubts.

- Is the transaction only mined after UpdateWeather has obtained Conditions and Temperature?
- what does the receipt contain? receipt contains Conditions and Temperature? If so, how do you extract the result?

  ```
  const transaction = myContract.methods.UpdateWeather(place);

  try {
                const options = {
                to      : transaction._parent._address,
                data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
                gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
                gasPrice: await getGasPrice(web3),
            };
        const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
        return receipt;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        const receipt = await getTransactionReceipt(web3);
        if (receipt)
            return receipt;
    }


  contract Booking
    {

        Weather  WeatherAddr ;


       constructor() public
       {
       }

       function UpdateWeather(bytes32  place_) public view returns(int256 Conditions ,int256 Temperature )
       {
          int256  Conditions ;
          int256  Temperature ;


        (Conditions, Temperature)=WeatherAddr.GetWeather(place_) ;

       }

    }



  contract Weather
    {
        function GetWeather(bytes32 place_) public view returns (int256, int256  retVal)
       {
          return(Places[place_].Conditions, Places[place_].Temperature) ;
       }
    }
  ```

Comment: This is really poor code (and I'm not even referring to the horrible indentation, or missing fragments like function `getTransactionReceipt` and so on). Function `UpdateWeather` doesn't change anything on the blockchain, and therefore doesn't even need to be executed in a transaction! Moreover, since this function doesn't return anything either, it seems pretty pointless to begin with.

Comment: @goodvibration I know this is horrible code and I apologize for not putting returns in UpdateWeather and for indentation,I'm trying to understand how this works. I'm sorry. I'm a beginner, so I don't know much about solidity and web3js

Comment: So please study the basics of both before jumping to sending signed transactions. It's pointless to answer your question when you're lacking the fundamentals (as reflected in the code that you've posted).

Comment: @goodvibration I am stalled. can you fix me this code and tell me how to proceed?